# Css Transition and Animations

Tags: css, animation, transition

Please take a look at my codepen for what I will be talking about:
     http://codepen.io/thingsbyting/pen/ywJhL

```
@-webkit-keyframes change {
  0% {
  background: purple;
  }
  100%{
  background: blue;
  }
}

div {
  background: purple;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width:320px;
  height:320px;
  -webkit-animation:change 3s linear infinite;
  -webkit-transition:background 1s;  
   p {
     padding-top: 120px;
     font-weight: bold;
     color: orange;
     font-size: 30px;
     text-align: center;
   }
}
```

I am playing around with CSS transitions and animations and I want the background colour of the circle to transition nicely from a purple to a blue. However, when it finishes it's transition from 0%-100% and starts again from 0% the colour change blinks instead of transitioning nicely. How can I make it so that this animation continuously transitions nicely  between the two colours?

Thanks!

Comment: You could either add [`animation-direction: alternate`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-animations/#valuedef-alternate) to that `div` or play with keyframes like **[this](http://codepen.io/hashem/pen/ubBmj)** to achieve the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a [JSFiddle Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tJeFp) with the solution. The change is here:

```
 -webkit-animation:change 3s linear infinite alternate;
```

For a detailed explanation please see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-direction

Comment: Thank you! This worked. Another solution I found was making the last colour the same as the first colour I set...which is essentially the same as the alternate keyword here! thanks again!

Comment: I would avoid your solution as you're repeating code. If you ever change the colour you'll have to update it in two places. Best to use alternate.

Answer (score 0):

you're looking for the `animation-direction` property

```
animation-direction: alternate;
```